# Drag and drop to target using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm doing a drag and drop game using jquery.

The objective of game is drag picture to a target div.

When drag the picture into the div target....It will alert "Correct" or "Incorrect" but I can not get it to work correctly.

I'm trying to do as follows:

```
      <img src="1.png" id="answer1">
      <img src="2.png" id="answer2">
      <img src="3.png" id="answer3">

      <div id="target1">
            drop here

       <script>
        $("#answer1").draggable();
        $("#answer2").draggable();
        $("#answer3").draggable();
        $("#target1").droppable({
  drop: function() {

                 if($("#target1:has(img.answer1)").length > 0)
                        {

                            alert('Correct');

                        }
                    else
                        {
                            alert('Incorrect');
                        }



                    }

                                });

</script>

      </div>
```

but always enters on the second condition doing the alert("Incorrect")

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Er, `img#answer1`, ID not class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check dragged element's id, you can get dragged element id like that in `drop` event: `ui.draggable.attr("id")`.

So change your script as

```
$("#answer1").draggable();
$("#answer2").draggable();
$("#answer3").draggable();
$("#target1").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.draggable.attr("id")=='answer1')
         {
              alert('Correct');
         }
         else
         {
              alert('Incorrect');
         }    
    }
});
```

You can check live demo in [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nU5TF/126/).

Comment: @user3497359  I am glad to help you.Don't forget to mark it as answer.You can Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.